# How to capture on change event on Django Autocomplete Light widget using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-events, django-autocomplete-light

I am using **Django Autocomplete Light** (DAL) in my application.

In order to do some post-processing in the background on user selection, I am trying to capture the `.on('change')` event (when DAL select field choice is changed) using jQuery (like we do on objects like an input field or a Django select field etc.). However I am not able to capture the event.

For example the following code (**edited**):

```
$(document).on('change', '#x_select_item', function() {
    console.log('Selection on x_select_item changed');
});
```

is **not generating any message**.

**Edit**

The following code for capturing `.on('focus)` is **working**:

```
$(document).on("focus", '#x_select_item', function() {
    console.log('THIS IS FIELD x_select_item for on Focus Event');
});
```

Looking for DAL events also did not help much excepting that it takes one to the "select2" events [page](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events). There are events listed including "change" and "change.select2", but using both of these (as in example above) are not generating any reaction in the console.

Is there some way **selection change event** may be captured on **DAL**?

Comment: Are you sure that your selector is selecting the correct thing? `$('#x_select_item')`

Comment: You are right. I have **modified the old example code** for `.on('change')` event in my question. And have also **added a new one** (for `.on('focus')`) **event**. But even now the situation remains same. I am able to capture the "**focus**" event, but not `.on('change')` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite an "older" question, but I just stumbled about nearly the same problem.

As I found out, there was a bug in older versions of DAL Django Autocomplete Light.
According to the issues in the github project it's fixed in versions >3.5

I've just upgraded to the latest version (v3.8.1) and change events are firing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed version 3.8.1 and i have to use this code for the change event to fired, is in the documentation:

```
$(':input[name$=continent]').on('change', function() {
   console.log("change fired");
});
```

where continent is the model field name, not the id of the select when you inspect the element in the html code.